# Connecting markers on seaborn scatterplot based on the hue color

Tags: python, seaborn

So I started to work on a visual using seaborn but I ran into a problem that I cannot wrap my head around. Basically I have 2 columns (start and end date) that I would like to link together based on my hue. The current graph is attached, the ideal final result would have the same hues linked via a line between them.
This is what I wrote so far to make these plots:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df, y=df.index, x='Start_Date', hue='Conf_Num', legend=False)
sns.scatterplot(data=df, y=df.index, x='End_Date', hue='Conf_Num', legend=False)
```

Sample Data
| Conf_Num | Start_Date     | End_Date  |
| :--------| :--------------: |-----------:|
| 0        | 2/8/2021       | 3/1/2021  |
| 1        | 2/15/2021      | 12/31/2021|
| 2        | 3/1/2021       | 8/29/2021 |

Any help or guidance is appreciated. [image: Current output]

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe as text instead of figure

Comment: is it always one start, one end?  Or could there be multiple starts/ends with the same hue?

Comment: I added sample data, hopefully the format looks good, I tried using the simple way of creating tables. @quasi-human

Comment: There is always one start and one end for each hue. the hue is my unique identifier. @Riley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have to appeal to matplotlib instead of seaborn.  Here is an example:

**test data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x":np.random.randint(10, size=10),
        "y":np.random.randint(10, size=10),
        "hue":[str(int(i/2)) for i in range(10)],
    }
)
```

**plot code**

```
_, ax = plt.subplots()

# choose a palette you like https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html
cmap = sns.color_palette("flare", n_colors=df["hue"].nunique())

for hue, color in zip(df["hue"].unique(), cmap):
    temp_df = df[df["hue"]==hue]
    ax.plot(temp_df["x"], temp_df["y"], marker="o", color=color)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method which recovers point hue data from plot (makes some possibly risky assumptions)

**test data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x":np.random.randint(10, size=10),
        "y":np.random.randint(10, size=10),
        "hue":[str(int(i/2)) for i in range(10)],
    }
)
```

**plot code**

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(data = df, x="x", y="y", hue="hue", cmap="bright")

pc = ax.collections[0]
point_data = pd.DataFrame(pc.get_offsets().data, columns=["x", "y"])
point_data["hue"] = pd.Series([tuple(arr) for arr in ax.collections[0].get_facecolor()])

for hue,  df_ in point_data.groupby("hue"):
    ax.plot(df_["x"], df_["y"], color=hue)
```